# classic asp FormatNumber displays a special character (Â) as the thousand seperator

Tags: asp-classic

I have a problem with the FormatNumber function in Classic ASP.

When this overload is used
   **FormatNumber(cdbl(aRecs(3, i)) , 0, 0, 0)**, the number appears fine e.g. 160 703

However, when this overload is used
   **FormatNumber(aRecs(3, i),0,false,false,true),"0")**, the number appears with a special character as the thousand seperator e.g. 160Â 703

N/B: **aRecs(3, i)** refers to a values being retrieved from a recordset (from the database).

On the production server(Windows Server 2008) **everything works fine**, however, when i setup a dev environment (windows 7 as well as Windows server 2008), thats were i get this problem. I have tried setting a thousand seperator in my regional settings to no avail

Am i missing something. Also, this is a very old project and i cannot go and modify all occurances of calls to this function.

Comment: This is probably an encoding problem - what chatacter encoding are you using on your page? windows-1251? UTF-8?

Comment: Yes apparently it was because of the encoding, i have applied the fix below, and i guess the behavior was because the encoding was not explicitly set, and MAYBE would default to the server encoding. I haven't found any place on the IIS server where i can set the encoding, other than the fix suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line of code to the top of your page:-

```
 Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
```

This problem is usually a result of a mismatch between the response code page (in your case I'm guessing 65001) and the CharSet value in the content type header.  Usually no CharSet value is delivered so the browsers guesses, typically using the current user locale to determine the codepage.

Comment: thanx Anthony, unfortunately i cannot vote your answer up because i do not have sufficient reputation... your response was spot on, solves my troubles. And i have added this line to a file that is included on all pages in the website, hence it now applies to all pages in my site.

Answer (score 0):

Use these two lines on the top of your page to correct this situation:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript codepage="65001"%>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```